# Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Server\Connection::__construct() ... called in DumpServerServiceProvider.php on line 49

Tags: php, laravel

Actual Error Message is

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Server\Connection::__const
  ruct() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\pa
  fg.com.bd\vendor\beyondcode\laravel-dump-server\src\DumpServerServiceProvid
  er.php on line 49
```

I setup my Existing Laravel Project in New PC (Machine). But, After complete all of the process i'm unable to run the project because of the mention error above.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[From innocenzi on GitHub](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-dump-server/issues/48#issuecomment-546121648):

> the issue comes from the fact that the configuration was cached without the `debug-server` config.
>
> Basically, the file `bootstrap/cache/config.php` doesn't contain the `debug-server` key. If you delete this file, you will most likely clear the error as well.

**Solution:**

Delete the file `yourProject/bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Comment: I have deleted cached config.php as you said but the issue was still there. I m using Laravel 8.51.

Comment: Simple restart your server hope the issue will be solve